Metadata on solscan not showing up
I created my metadata with createMetadataAccountV3 with the tx being recorded onchain her, but i am still not able to view my token metadata on solscan. I am able to view the icon on phantom wallet and the metadata on solexplorer as well. Does anyone have a fix to this?
transaction:
https://solscan.io/tx/wSggMZjpYrRwnK5KfzvR9d6fpzcXGBfLtbwmSd3iBh3c62GgAUzqjZmxQ5f9TqEgA8viznTeYMJJqYDvUbQE81R?cluster=devnet
mint address: https://solscan.io/token/C2bW5R54snUHz8Hcot9Q2y4JUmTXVsKTMq8PiyxEs6dW?cluster=devnet
